# Compute the projection matrix P onto a line that goes through the vector $\vec a$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, projection-matrices

I've computed the result using the formula our teacher gave using P = ($\vec a$*$\vec a^T$)/($\vec a^T$*$\vec a$) which gives me a scalar (9) divided by a not invertible matrix. I assume this is wrong because in other examples I see "(1/scalar)*matrix=P".  The vector $\vec a$ = (1,2,-2).

Comment: I think you're mixed up - $a^{T} a$ should be a scalar.

Comment: The https://matrixcalc.org/en/#%7B%7B1%7D,%7B2%7D,%7B-2%7D%7D%2A%7B%7B1,2,-2%7D%7D (matrix calculator) says it's a matrix.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Vectors are supposed to be columns. A matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 2 & -2}$ is not a vector in the sense of your formula. The problem is a bit subtle, since of course row vectors *are* vectors. The precise statement is that your formula only applies in the case that $\vec{a}$ is a *column* vector.

Comment: I checked simmilar assigments and noticed that on this example I gave, the teacher probably forgot the T so it probably should be $\vec a$ = $\left[ 1   +2  -2 \right]^{T}$

Comment: I think that the notation (with commas) e.g. $\vec{x} = (1,0,0)$ is usually used to denote a column vector